# How to create an object file from multiple sources taking into account compilation flags?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, g++, ld

I have multiple object files that are compiled with some libary linking and option (costumary for the libraries).
The makefile ends with

```
    $(PROG): lots.o of.o objects.o $(COMPLIB) $(LUA_OBJS)
    $(CC) `$(CONFIGTHREADS)` -rdynamic -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--version-script lua.vers -DGTK $^ -o $@ $(CONFIGLIB) $(LIBDL) -lm -lstdc++
```

where, as usual $(CC) is the C++ compiler, $(COMPLIB) is a library.a file, $(LUA_OBJ) another big chunk of external object...
The big conondrum is in $(CONFIGLIB) that is a linking and configuration (with some compulsory options, like -pthread) of $(LIBDL) and libm and liblstdc++.

The total resulting command, in my particular case, is:

``` g++ `` -rdynamic -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--version-script lua.vers -DGTK lots.o of.o ojbects.o -o executable.x -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0   -ldl -lm -lstdc++ ```

But the point is that instead of releasing the executable, I would like to wrap up all of this, libraries and compiling options included, into an elegant .o or .a file in order to be used as an object for another project, whatever option the complex makefile might require.

I'm aware of the existence of

```
ar crv library.a lots.o of.o objects.o
```

or

```
ld -r lots.o of.o objects.o -o wrap.o
```

But both of them give error when I try to add the options, also the very important and complicated ones related to the library.

The errors are:
with ld: unrecognized option '-pthread' 
with ar: two different operation options specified

moreover if I wrap the lots.o of.o objects.o with ar crv (or ar rv) obtaining a wrap.a, 
`g++ wrap.a -o program.x -lots -of -options` does not work. While creating object with ld -r works.

The workaround I have in mind is to compile all the objects with the options individually and then wrap up, but this will imply a serious rewrite of the makefile and probably blow out of scale my compiling times.

Comment: Perhaps you can find somebody on the internet who can look at the error messages and explain what's wrong with what you are doing.

Comment: with ld: unrecognized option '-pthread'

with ar: two different operation options specified

Comment: Can you post the exact commands you are running? I don't see a `-pthread` in the line involving `ld` that you posted.

Comment: Please edit your question with relevant information.

Comment: I edited posting the exact command, @Xymostech.
but, I don't think the specific call is a "relevant information" here because the call can change when the makefile options change, but I would like in any case to wrap up a single object starting from many of them and including, if possible, compilation options in the new object.

I just would like to include

Comment: I don't think exactly what you ask is possible. But you should be able to achieve similar result with [pkgconfig](http://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html).